# I try to run cypress, but always return me a error "dri3 extension not supported"

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, debian, cypress

When I try to execute this command:

```
npx cypress open
```

then the terminal return me a *error*:

> "ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported". I

Can't resolve this.
Create a cypress structure.

Comment: Nothing to do with bash I think.

Answer (score 7):

this happens because where you want to test your cypress code, cypress cant use a GPU for whatever reason. I had the same problem when running it in one of their docker files. Use this in your `index.js` file, it detects before your tests starts what browser you are using and disables GPU acceleration (as far as i know it only works for chrome so you have to use `npx cypress run --browser chrome` when you want to run your tests)

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
      console.log(launchOptions.args)
  
      if (browser.name == 'chrome') {
        launchOptions.args.push('--disable-gpu')
      }
  
      return launchOptions
    }),
  }
```

Maybe one of those could help: 
[GitHub issue 5889](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5889) 
[GitHub issue 564](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action/issues/564)

Answer (score 2):

If you run it on a virtual machine, try to look at this:
https://shouv.medium.com/how-to-run-cypress-on-wsl2-989b83795fb6
Otherwise, I suggest using docker images to run Cypress to get rid of all dependencies problems.
https://hub.docker.com/u/cypress